# Good locations for config file? (shared between users, common per machine)

Tags: java, windows, windows-shell

I'm currently writing a replacement shell in java for windows, and my application is currently creating a config file using

```
File userSettings = new File("Gyroscope.properties");
```

However, when this is run by windows, the current directory is set to `C:\windows\System32\` and the program doesn't have write permissions to this directory.

What would be a better location for the configuration file to be written to? It would be preferable to have it relative to the jar file, however I do not know a good method of doing so, and other stack overflow questions have had unclean solutions to this exact problem, so I am looking for other locations as options.

The configuration is machine specific, and should be common to all users.

Comment: How about the user's home directory?

Comment: If you want it relative to the jar, did you try getting the current working directory from the code and then creating the file relative to that path?

Comment: Yes, that is how I ran into the issue in the first place, the current directory changes to the system root once it is run as a shell.

Comment: @tobias_k The problem with the user's home directory is that my use case is machine dependent, not user dependent, so customizing it for every user would be detrimental, instead of helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class, it'll make sure that the settings are written to somewhere where it's allowed (such as user's home dir or the registry).

Comment: With the Preferences class, where exactly do the config options end up? I need to be able to document where it will be, the advantage with this however is that it lets me choose to not be user dependent, which storing it in the users home directory would not allow me to do.

Comment: It depends on the platform. On Unix it would save to something like ~/.java_profile/

Answer (score 1):

I will describe a possible solution. There should be several way to achieve it.

Put your config file next to your jar. Put explicitly the config file in your classpath while invoking java (e.g. `java -cp .../Gyroscope.jar;.../Gyroscope.properties <your_main_class>`).

Now you can access your properties file as a ressource (ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/Gyroscope.properties"). Use whatever classloader you want as soon as it is convenient and cleam for your actual implementation. Once your have an inputstream, you can load your properties into a Properties object as usual.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This helps, but it moves the problem towards proper documentation of how to set the class path correctly for the people to follow.

Comment: Indeed, you have to document and/or provide a launcher shell script (.sh, .bat, ...). By the way, whatever the choosen solution, you will have to document it anyway. ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't mind using a shell script to launch it, however it leaves a command prompt window open with all the debug information inside of it.

Comment: How do you intend to spawn your jvm?

Comment: Using a Group Policy Object to run it as a shell, which is most similar to running it from CommandPrompt with a Current Directory of the system room e.g. C:\windows\system32\ However I am starting to believe that a java launcher of some kind may be more suitable, however that just pushes the problem to the launcher.

Comment: Actually this combined with a VBScript to launch the jar would be a good option, however  I am not strong enough in VB to craft a solution.

Comment: Why not looking at http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/ ? This is one of the few launcher you can find with google (keywords "java launcher windows").